# MVC Viewbag Group By and count unique item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Hello guys I am new to Asp.net, So I have a question here. What i am trying to do is to use Group by and count in my Viewbag.

The code bellow is ok, but i need the count function.

```
 ViewBag.details= db.Items
       .Where(x => x.Title.StartsWith(title)).GroupBy(a => a.UserId)
       .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
       .OrderBy(b => b.Users.State)
        .ToList();
```

So the code it is working like:

London
China
Japan

but i need it to count individually like:

London (2)
China (6)
Japan (5)

Many thanks. Fernando.

Comment: Try adding .Count() to it.

Comment: So I have tried but it gave me an error, Many thanks Ric.

Comment: Can you share your view code?

Comment: It is basic like: @foreach (var mylist ViewBag.details)
    
{
    <li>@mylist.Users.State</li>
  }

Comment: What is your Item Model looks like?

Comment: @user3043560 what is the error? and where are you placing .Count()?

Comment: I am placing before the .ToList().

Comment: You need to cast your ViewBag to List of items. So basically you need to do this:

@foreach (var item in (List<YourModel>ViewBag.details)

Comment: marco, i think that's incorrect analysis of the issue. the user needs to get a count per each grouping. casting may or may not help at the end of the pipeline, but will not solve the problem at hand. sorry, just an observation, not an attack on your comment

Comment: @jimtollan Jim you are correct no offense taken. I didn't read his problem properly I thought he was having an issue in the view with the foreach loop. I believe the answer you offer is correct...

Comment: marco - hard to know if my answer is correct, as there's no model to examine. however, it'll be there or there abouts i reckon :-). take care and let's see how it pans out..

Answer (score 0):

After calling `GroupBy`, you get a series of groups - `IEnumerable<Grouping>`, where each Grouping itself exposes the `Key` used to create the group plus it also contains an IEnumerable of whatever items are in your original data set. You just have to call `Count()` on that Grouping to get the subtotal.

However, the lack of any concrete model in your OP makes for a bumpy road here, so best estimates prevail, tho I think this should take you most of the way there.

Actions (and code) speak louder than words:

```
ViewBag.details = db.Items
    .Where(x => x.Title.StartsWith(title))
    .GroupBy(a => a.Users.State)
    .Select(n => new
    {
        Location = n.Key,
        Entity = n.FirstOrDefault(),
        LocationCount = n.Count()
    })
    .OrderBy(n => n.Location)
    .ToList();
```

untested and potentially iffy (Users.State looks potentially problematic). full class structure would clear the mist instantly.

**[edit]** - noticed the original code added the FirstOrDefault() entity to the result, so amended to included too.